# Using bearer token authentication with HTTP Live Streaming?

Tags: http-live-streaming, bearer-token

My scenario with expected outcome:

1. User logs into a web portal.
2. The web portal presents content which is allowed to be accessed by the user.
3. The user selects a piece of content, which directs their browser to the m3u8 file for that content.
4. Each piece of content has an encryption key. The m3u8 file includes a URL for the key for that video, which is a REST endpoint with a query string (e.g. `https://www.mymediaserver.com/api/key/100`
5. The REST API will deliver the key in raw form to the requester *if and only if* a bearer token is provided along with the request. The key used to process the token is the same as the key used for the frontend API (e.g. that lists video content available). In other words, the same Authorization header that the user agent provides with API requests to populate the frontend can also be used for key retrieval. (This is not ideal, but it's a start and this project is more proof-of-concept at this stage.)
6. The video player would include the `Authorization` header with the request, and thus receive the key and be able to play the content.

Here are my questions:

- The intended use case is simply to play the video within the browser. I could use a `<video>` tag, or even just redirect the browser to the file to begin playing the content full-screen on its own, and the user would use the Back button after playback.
- I haven't yet started building all of this out because I'm not sure how the video playback engine actually requests the key. Is there a way to modify the HTTP request used to get the key, such that I can add the `Authorization` header?
- Or, perhaps, does the video player automatically add the appropriate existing `Authorization` header?

Theories I've had:

- I could dynamically generate the m3u8 file, adding the bearer token as a query string parameter. But, I'd then have to figure out how to get my REST endpoint to read the bearer token from the query string instead of from the headers. This would be an extra step.
- I could generate my own one-time-use key retrieval strings and combine it with the above idea, but I then have to add the extra infrastructure to store the keys, expire them upon use, etc.

The summary question:

- How do I implement bearer tokens when setting up a REST-style endpoint which will provide decryption keys for HLS video packages?

Notes:

- The backend API is a C# ASP.NET Web API project.
- The frontend for video selection is Angular.
- I only plan to support iOS for now for this project.
- I am aware that particularly crafty users may be able to figure out how to retrieve the keys. I'm trying to prevent casual downloading of video content from the server. (I fully realize you can't prevent copying, but you can prevent *casual*, easy copying.)
- This is currently just a proof-of-concept idea for an internal video hosting platform that would make it at least challenging to retrieve video content for playback outside of the web site and without authentication.